# Maximum sum when going through matrix for number of turns

Tags: java, matrix

You have a matrix and you may start at any point.
You can go in any one of the 8 directions(down,down-left,left,left-up etc.).
For every position you're at, you add that position's value to a **sum**.
After you've been to a position, it's value becomes 0.
The challenge consists of creating a **recursive** algorithm for returning the highest sum starting from the given point.

My **question** is: My method doesn't work.Can you help me modify my method so it can work?

This is my code:

```
public int travel (int i, int j,int k,int sum)
    {
        //value temporarily takes the position's value
        int value;

        //if position is out of matrix bounds
        if(i>=x||j>=y||i<0||j<0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //makes the value in point (i,j) = 0
            value=M[i][j];
            M[i][j]=0;

            //if the number of turns has been reached
            if(k==turns)
            {
                //restores value at position
                M[i][j]=value;
                return M[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                //loop for going to all 8 neighbors
                for(int line=-1;line<2;line++)
                {
                    for(int col=-1;col<2;col++)
                    {
                        //if the position is the same
                        if(!(col==0&&line==0))
                        {
                            sum=Math.max(travel(i+line,j+col,k+1,sum), sum);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //restores value at position
                M[i][j]=value;

                //returns sum so far
                return sum+M[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

For matrix:

```
    9 2 7 4 
    2 8 3 7
    5 1 2 4
    1 9 8 3

turns: 3
starting point: (0,0) (of value 9)
```

It should return 31. The path is down-right,up-right,down-right (9+8+7+7=31)

Comment: I think the question is obvious: how to fix the code? But i really didnt get want you to do, yet. So you start at any position and walk through the matrix, summing up the highest neighbors and returning if you reach a position where you would need to go back?

Comment: You start at a point and you want to form a path so that the sum of values is highest. Where you have been already the value becomes zero (so it would be pointless to go back).

Comment: yes but you could say "well than i take the next highest value", so extending your example path you would walk top or bottom to the value 4 as next step.

Comment: are you only supposed to do 4 steps? Why can't you go to 4 next?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "top or bottom to value 4". You can't go greedy and just select the highest neighbor. The path sum has to be highest.

Comment: You can go only from neighbor to neighbor, distance of 1 unit in any of the 8 directions, if you will.

Comment: yes but what do you mean by that? 31 + 4 = 35 is obviously higher than just 31. Do you mean you need the highest sum in relation to steps? So sum/steps has to be max?

Comment: The number of turns has been reached at 7. You can't go 4 turns. step 1:9-->8, step 2:8-->7, step 3:7-->7.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? what result it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
   public static int travel (int i, int j,int k)
   {
    //value temporarily takes the position's value
    int value;

    //if position is out of matrix bounds
    if(i>=x||j>=y||i<0||j<0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //makes the value in point (i,j) = 0
        value=M[i][j];
        M[i][j]=0;

        //if the number of turns has been reached
        if(k==turns)
        {
            //restores value at position
            M[i][j]=value;
            return M[i][j];
        }
        else
        {   
            int sum = 0;
            //loop for going to all 8 neighbors
            for(int line=-1;line<2;line++)
            {
                for(int col=-1;col<2;col++)
                {
                    //if the position is the same
                    if(!(col==0&&line==0))
                    {
                        sum=Math.max(travel(i+line,j+col,k+1), sum);
                    }
                }
            }

            //restores value at position
            M[i][j]=value;

            //returns sum so far
            return sum+M[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is the `sum` parameter. Because, after a turn, the `sum` value has been updated, and you also pass this updated value to the next turn, which made the whole thing getting bigger and bigger